# not writing in text file on server side using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to put the results from the database into a text file after fetching it, and if the text file doesnt exist it creates one and put the data into it. after that i showed the the data by extracting from those txt files in another page. the problem is it is working fine in my local xampp server. but i dont know why its not working in my aws account. the result page shows blank in aws elastic ip.but its connecting to the database and if there is no results found it also shows the message. so its just not putting the datas into the txt file nt even creating it. i tried by creating the txt file manually. still not working. but its working fine in my local server. Here is the code i used-

```
$wineFile ="WineName.txt";
file_put_contents($wineFile, $W);
```

Comment: Do you have permission to write the file?

Comment: Also it is worth to check the result of invoking `file_put_contents`

Comment: What is the message it's showing, if no results are found?

Comment: putvande -I don't know. how to check that?? David- when it cant find any result, it just redirect to the page i created. but when it find the results, it doesn't show, jst doesnt write into the text file or even not creates the text file

Comment: echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('WineName.txt')), -4);- what is the output ?

Comment: metalfight - 33204 this is the output.

Comment: metalfight - sorry this is the output - 0664

Comment: @user2702191 You're going to have to give us more code than that. We can asssume and guess **"Till the Cows come home"**, but they'll never "get home", if you know what I mean. ;-)

Comment: @user2702191 And how is the `$W` variable being defined?

Answer (score 0):

From your comments , seems like there is not enough permission.  You need to **`CHMOD 777`** on the file.

So make use of **CHMOD** command on PHP
Something like this

```
  $file ="WineName.txt";
    chmod($file, 0777); 
    $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$wineFile = "WineName.txt";
$fh = fopen($wineFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Tasty Wine\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```